# formula with IF and count if not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula but it is showing an error:

`=IF(COUNTIF(B6:AF6,">=1")">=5","Met","Not Met")`

Regards,

Pandya Raj

Comment: not sure of logic, but =IF(COUNTIF(B6:AF6,">=1")>=5,"Met","Not Met") should at least be valid syntactically... ie remove qoutes

Answer (score 1):

This should be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B6:AF6,">=1")>=5,"Met","Not Met")
```